# how to show product list in homepage without using feature product feature

Tags: nopcommerce

I want to show all products in Home.When I click one category from category navigation menu,all products of that category are displayed as list or grid.I want to show all products in nop database like that one without using feature products(show on home page properties from admin page).

Comment: you want a lot.. but what have you done so far ?

Comment: nope.I want to know how to show all products from database without using using feature products(show on home page properties from admin page).I need to edit my question?